# update case class fields using shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have the following types defined:

```
sealed trait Refreshable {
  val expireAt: Instant
  val version: Int
}

case class A(id: Int, expireAt: Instant, version: Int) extends Refreshable

case class B(name: String, expireAt: Instant, version: Int) extends Refreshable
```

I would like to define a method `refresh` that updates two fields on these types, but I cannot find the implicits I need for this. It seems like I should be able to do something like this with shapeless ?

```
def refresh[T <: RefreshableClass])(v: T)(implicit ev: LabelledGeneric[T]) = {
  val gen = ev.from(v)

  gen.updateWith('expire)(_.plus(...)).updateWith('version)(_+1)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably simplest way is to use shapeless lenses. First, some imports:

```
import java.time._
import shapeless._
```

Inheritance from common trait is not required if fields match, so for the purpose of this example I'll remove it:

```
case class A(id: Int, expireAt: Instant, version: Int)
case class B(name: String, expireAt: Instant, version: Int)
```

Create paths selecting the product element labelled expireAt / version

```
val (expirePath, versionPath) = (^.expireAt, ^.version)
```

Write your method accepting lens factories for given paths:

```
def refresh[T](t: T)(implicit
                    expireL: expirePath.Lens[T, Instant],
                    versionL: versionPath.Lens[T, Int]): T = {
  val t1 = expireL().set(t)(Instant.now())
  val t2 = versionL().modify(t1)(_ + 1)

  t2
}
```

Use it:

```
println(refresh(A(1, null, 0)))
println(refresh(B("The B", null, 4)))
```

Comment: Possibly some import is missing? `could not find implicit value for parameter expireL...`. I tried to make val (expirePath... implicit but get the same error

Comment: @simao works in scastie w/ Scala 2.12.3 & shapeless 2.3.2. [(here)](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/izvobOwaSLSImztyW2VEYg). Maybe your field is named differently or has different type, not `Instant`?

Comment: ah yeah that was the problem. This is very good thanks. Is there a way to combine the lens ? ie a lens that extracts expire and version ?

Comment: @simao you can combine shapeless lenses with `~` operator, e.g. `val lens = expireL() ~ versionL()`, giving you a lens to tuple

Comment: I get this error: `value applyDynamic is not a member of object shapeless.Path
[error] error after rewriting to shapeless.`package`.^.<applyDynamic: error>("version")
[error] possible cause: maybe a wrong Dynamic method signature?
[error]   val c = ^.expires() ~ ^.version()` So not sure what is wrong with that?

Comment: @simao `^.expires` is a path, not a lens. You need to create lenses for concrete type `T` before you can combine them (in my examples it is done by receiving lens factories as implicit parameters).

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Make your trait sealed.</strike>

```
sealed trait Refreshable {
  val expireAt: Instant
  val version: Int
}
```

---

With [Typelevel Scala](https://typelevel.org/scala/) the following variant works:

```
def refresh[T <: Refreshable, R <: HList](v: T)(implicit
  generic: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, R],
  modifier: Modifier.Aux[R, Symbol @@ "version", Int, Int, R],
  modifier1: Modifier.Aux[R, Symbol @@ "expireAt", Instant, Instant, R]): R = {
  val rec = generic.to(v)
  val rec1 = modifier(rec, _ + 1)
  modifier1(rec1, _.plus(1L, ChronoUnit.MILLIS))
}
```

With Lightbend Scala (i.e. standard Scala)

```
def refresh[T <: Refreshable, R <: HList](v: T)(implicit
  generic: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, R],
  modifier: Modifier.Aux[R, Witness.`'version`.T, Int, Int, R],
  modifier1: Modifier.Aux[R, Witness.`'expireAt`.T, Instant, Instant, R]): R = {
  val rec = generic.to(v)
  val rec1 = modifier(rec, _ + 1)
  modifier1(rec1, _.plus(1L, ChronoUnit.MILLIS))
}
```

---

If you prefer to work with `updateWith` this is also possible:

```
def refresh[T <: Refreshable, R <: HList](v: T)(implicit
  generic: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, R],
  modifier: Modifier.Aux[R, Witness.`'version`.T, Int, Int, R],
  modifier1: Modifier.Aux[R, Witness.`'expireAt`.T, Instant, Instant, R],
  selector: Selector.Aux[R, Witness.`'version`.T, Int],
  selector1: Selector.Aux[R, Witness.`'expireAt`.T, Instant]): R = {
  val rec = generic.to(v)
  rec.updateWith('expireAt)(_.plus(1L, ChronoUnit.MILLIS))
    .updateWith('version)(_ + 1)
}
```

---

Normally you don't need to specify type parameters `T` and `R`, they should be inferred:

```
refresh(A(1, Instant.now, 1)) //1 :: 2017-09-20T18:53:34.039Z :: 2 :: HNil
refresh(B("a", Instant.now, 1)) // a :: 2017-09-20T18:53:34.074Z :: 2 :: HNil
```

But if you do need you can specify them:

```
refresh[A, Record.`'id -> Int, 'expireAt -> Instant, 'version -> Int`.T](A(1, Instant.now, 1))
refresh[B, Record.`'name -> String, 'expireAt -> Instant, 'version -> Int`.T](B("a", Instant.now, 1))
```

Comment: Yes but that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @simao What version of shapeless are you using? It's not 2.3.2, is it?

Comment: I don't expect the code I am using to work, there is something missing here, I just don't know what it is. I am using shapeless 2.3.2

Comment: @DmytroMitin you should be able to remove `R1` and `R2` and use `R` in their places, since you're not changing the shape of HList in any way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot get this to work because I would have to specify the type R when calling the function which I cannot do, due to the way I am calling this function.

Comment: @simao I updated my answer with examples. Normally you don't need to specify type parameters `T` and `R`, they should be inferred. But if you do need you can specify them.